# multinomial stats question

Tags: statistics

A certain game you spin a wheel that cocnsists

- 10 red markers
- 15 black markers
- 4 Blue Markers
- 1 Gold Markers

what is the prob we get
  -  2 Red
  -  4 Black
  - 2 Green (Blue)
  -  2 Gold
out 10 spins

---

It is Multinomial

$$ \frac{n!}{X_1! X_2! \dots X_n!}$$

where $p_1 = 2/10;p_2 = 4/15,p_3=2/4,p_4=2/2$

so 
$$\frac {10! }{2! 4! 2! 2!} (2/10)^2 (4/15)^4 (2/4)^2 (2/2)^2$$

***Appreciate a critique Thanks!!!!***

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In total the wheel has $30 (=10+15+4+1)$ markers. Thus the probability to get a red marker after one spin is $p_1=\frac{10}{30}$. Equivalently the probability to get a black marker after one spin is $p_2=\frac{15}{30}$. Similar calculations for the other colors.

Also note that $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$. The multinomial coefficient is correct.